# ZFS on RAID6 over iSCSI

Tags: zfs, iscsi, hardware-raid

We are planning to deploy a ~100TB storage onto our Debian systems.

The storage consists of an external enclosure (`EonStore D1000: ESDS1024`) with 24 6TB-disks, that connects to a single host via iSCSI over a 10GBit fibre.

Because the storage is already quite large and we might want to expand it in the future, we'd like to use ZFS as the filesystem.

Now the `EonStore D1000`, comes pre-configured as a RAID6 system and also supports hardware-encryption (SED). It *could* also be configured as JBOD.

I read that ZFS should never be used on hardware RAIDs and instead prefers to  get direct access to the harddisks.

However, I'm not sure whether this holds true for iSCSI devices as well (e.g. does iSCSI report enough info to ZFS to make its fault correction shine in relation to the built-in RAID6?)

Also, we are tempted to use SED, which I *guess* will not play together with ZFS's fault correction at all.

So my question: should I (still) avoid RAID6 at all costs in RAIDZ instead? how about encryption?

Comment: *Now the EonStore D1000, comes pre-configured as a RAID6 system*  ***ONE*** 24-disk RAID6 array, using 6TB drives?!?!?!  Hopefully not.  And if so, hopefully you're not planning on using it that way.  Even if performance is acceptable in such a configuration (there's a good chance it won't be), RAID rebuild times are going to be horrible, opening quite a significant window for losing access to your data if you get multiple drive failures during any rebuild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read that ZFS should never be used on hardware RAIDs and instead
>   prefers to get direct access to the harddisks.

In this case: Bollocks.

Here is the gist. If you run this as ZFS vs JBOD you multiply your already bad UI bandwidth (10G is NOT a lot). If you run it as Raid 6 then spawn something non redundant on it, you do not deal with redundant network traffic. Case closed.

Use enclosure management to handle enclosure failures. Use the enclosure EACH as "a disc" (with a Raid 6 below) and use ZFS non-redundant storage (or go mirroring if you want to go really crazy, which sometimes makes sense).

It really runs down on performance and seriously, for 24 discs 10G is not exactly ample. You want to avoid redundant network traffic, which happens when you do software based Raid with remote discs.

Comment: How is it redundant?

Comment: If you send similar data multiple times then this is redundant. ZFS on storage means client sends data once. TFS over ISCSI means the data bloat hits the - in this case pathetically slow at 10g - network.

Comment: Similar data? What if your using a cache? I dont use a raid, but I use a zfs over iscsi nas w a cache on a 1GB and it works great